# R: error with read_csv, 'sysdata.rdb': No such file or directory

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I'm trying to use read_csv in R from tidyverse package but I always get this message:

```
> read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"))
Error in date_names_lang(date_names) : 
  cannot open file '~/R/win-library/3.4/readr/R/sysdata.rdb': No such file or directory
```

The file and the directory does exist:

```
> list.files("~/R/win-library/3.4/readr/R/")
[1] "readr"       "readr.rdb"   "readr.rdx"   "sysdata.rdb" "sysdata.rdx"
```

I've the latest version of R and of the tidyverse:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.0     purrr_0.2.2.2   readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11     compiler_3.4.0   cellranger_1.1.0 plyr_1.8.4       forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.0      jsonlite_1.5    
 [8] lubridate_1.6.0  gtable_0.2.0     nlme_3.1-131     lattice_0.20-35  rlang_0.1.1      psych_1.7.5      parallel_3.4.0  
[15] haven_1.0.0      xml2_1.1.1       stringr_1.2.0    httr_1.2.1       hms_0.3          grid_3.4.0       glue_1.0.0      
[22] R6_2.2.1         readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-67   reshape2_1.4.2   modelr_0.1.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1    
[29] assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5     rvest_0.3.2      colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.5    lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3   
[36] broom_0.4.2
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Check if the file exists at the path you get when you type this: `readr_example("mtcars.csv")` If not, change your working directory: `setwd()`

Comment: The file did exist. The problem solved itself (I don't know how). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I restarted R, reinstalled `readr` and it worked. Here are more links that might shed some light:

https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/46

https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/428

Comment: I looked into those issues but withou help. The problem solved itself (I don't know how). Thanks anyway

Comment: For me, the error reappears if I use RStudio's checkboxes to load packages as opposed to typing `library(tidyverse)`. RStudio adds a `lib.loc` argument that  is different from the default.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue when running TCGAbiolinks.

In addition to the suggestion by idecico, I found loading readr via library(readr) before other packages like tidyverse, solved the issue (based on a comment by mrscholz on the following github page: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/46)